# How to operate some elements in a 2-D tensor with dynamic dimension in TensorFlow

Tags: sorting, dynamic, tensorflow

I have a 2-D tensor A with shape (m, n), but m and n are unknown. e.g. A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], here m=2 and n=3. After my operation, I want to get B=[[1,20,3],[4,5,60]]. The operation is like this:

1) Sort all elements in A with descending order: 6,5,4,3,2,1

2) Select 6, which means row 2 and col 3 are occupied;

3) Skip 5,4 and 3, because row 2 or col 3 is already occupied;

4) Select 2, because row 1 and col 2 are not occupied;

5) Stop, since all the rows are occupied (similarly for all the cols)

6) selected elements * 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer after discussing with my friend:

```
A=A-tf.reduce_min(A)
mask=A*0

def body(x,mask):
 a=x-tf.reduce_max(x)
 a=tf.sign(a)+1
 mask=mask+a
 where = tf.equal(x, tf.reduce_max(x))
 indices = tf.where(where)
 indices = tf.cast(indices, "int32")
 col_slice=tf.slice(x, [0, indices[0][1]], [-1, 1])
 col_slice=col_slice-tf.reduce_max(col_slice)
 col_slice=-tf.sign(col_slice)
 col_slice = tf.reshape(col_slice, [-1])
 b=tf.matmul(tf.diag(col_slice),x)
 row_slice=tf.slice(x, [indices[0][0],0], [1,-1])
 row_slice=row_slice-tf.reduce_max(row_slice)
 row_slice=-tf.sign(row_slice)
 row_slice=tf.reshape(row_slice,[-1])
 c=tf.matmul(b,tf.diag(row_slice))
 return (c,mask)

def cond(x,mask):
 return tf.greater(tf.reduce_sum(x),0)

_,final_mask=tf.while_loop(cond, body,(A,mask))
final_mask=final_mask*9+1
B=A*final_mask
```